# How can I move the window without titleBar and fully filled with webView?

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa

I'm working on something similar to the native picture in picture.

[image: My window]

I want to move this window, but can't because there is no titlebar (it's hidden and `window.stylemask` is `fullSizeContentView`) in it and it's fully filled with the webView.

So, I can't just click on titlebar and drag to move this window.

P.S.
Sorry for my english. I hope the goal is clear

Comment: @EricAya I want move the window in which is the webView.

Comment: @EricAya but there are no titlebar (it is hidden and `window.stylemask` is `fullSizeContentView`) in it and it is fully filled with webView. So I can't just click on titlebar and drag to move this window. Do you understand?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can subclass the webview to catch `-mouseDown:` events, and then pass the NSEvent to [`-[NSWindow performWindowDragWithEvent:]`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/appkit/nswindow/1419386-performwindowdragwithevent?language=objc).

Apple has [sample code](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/PhotoEditor/Listings/Photo_Editor_WindowDraggableButton_swift.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40017384-Photo_Editor_WindowDraggableButton_swift-DontLinkElementID_22) which uses this technique to start a window drag after the mouse moves some minimum distance, while still handling normal clicks. If you want to support basic interaction with the webview, this might be a good approach.

(Overriding `-mouseDown:` seems to work for WKWebView, it may not work with the legacy WebView. It's a bit of a hack, but you could use an overlay view to catch those events instead.)

Comment: Seems like it will not work it subclass of webView directly.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5341278/mousedown-not-firing-in-webview-subclass

Comment: but you probably sent me in the right direction. I'll try to create overlay view and override this method as shown in the documentation

Comment: Yes, it works as expected. I'll mark the answer as correct, but, please, add about overlay view. I could edit, but my English is curve more than completely

Answer (score 0):

If you remove the two lines with `highlight(true)` (line 18) and `self.highlight(false)` (line ~40) the sample code works also for WKWebView.